# Safe String Functions In Mac OS X and Linux

Tags: c++, windows, linux, security, macos

are there are equivalent secure string functions in Mac OSX and Linux just like the ones in Windows (strcpy_s,strncpy_s..etc) ?

What about functions that convert between multi-byte and wide characters?

Comment: If using C++ use syd::String and string buffers rather than these - thesw should only be used in C not C++

Comment: I have a need to operate with C strings, too.

Comment: `std::string` has an interface for dealing with C interfaces: `str.c_str()` will return a `char const*` that you can pass to C APIs.

Comment: I know, but I need functionality beyond simply sending a const char* to a function.

Comment: I would do the changing of the data in your code using the C++ classes and then pass the C string to code you call.

Comment: OS X has the safer string functions from BSD. On Linux, you can install the `libbsd` package. The Debian package is `libbsd-dev`, and the Fedora package is `libbsd-devel`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two strategies for safe string manipulation. The Linux / [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/) maintainers refuse to add safe functions, arguing that you should keep the length of your strings at hand and use `memcpy`.

On the other hand, Mac OSX includes `strlcpy` and `strlcat` from BSD. [`snprintf`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/snprintf.3.html) and [`asprintf`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/asprintf.3.html) can be used on both platforms to much the same effect:

```
size_t strlcpy(char *d, char const *s, size_t n)
{
    return snprintf(d, n, "%s", s);
}

size_t strlcat(char *d, char const *s, size_t n)
{
    return snprintf(d, n, "%s%s", d, s);
}
```

You could also consider using the BSD implementation [found here](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/string/). If your code will be compiled on multiple platforms, you can test for the presence of glibc using [pre-defined library macros](http://predef.sourceforge.net/prelib.html):

```
#if defined __GNU_LIBRARY__ || defined __GLIBC__

    size_t strlcpy(char *, char const *, size_t);
    size_t strlcat(char *, char const *, size_t);

#endif
```

Conversion between character encodings is most easily handled using the [`iconv`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/iconv.3.html) interface.

Comment: I needed a simple implementation of `strlcpy` and `strlcat` for a tool I'm porting to Linux, but **these do not work as expected**; when I swap to this implementation I'm getting large amounts of missing output. Replacing them with the BSD implementation (http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/string/) produces the expected results.

Comment: Seems the OpenBSD source has moved - new link is http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/string/

Answer (score 4):

OSX has `strlcpy` and `strlcat`. Linux doesn't currently have them, to my knowledge, but it's easy enough to bring those functions in from, say, OpenBSD.

Comment: What about wide-character to multi-byte conversions?

Comment: @Voulnet: It's uncommon in the Unix world to use wide characters (most programs use UTF-8 instead), so it's a non-issue for the most part.

Answer (score 3):

You can use gcc's `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2` option, for Linux you can go more advanced, for that you should read [Secure Programming with gcc & glibc](http://cansecwest.com/csw08/csw08-holtmann.pdf) .

Comment: `FORTIFY_SOURCE=2` will only work as you hope if GCC can deduce the destination buffer size. In many instances it cannot. If GCC cannot deduce the buffer size, then the original unsafe function remains. Its better to explicitly use a "safer" string function.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use char buffers (NTBS=Nul terminated byte strings) there are *no* instrinsically safe string functions. Not even strlen() is safe.

Rather, there are intrinsically **unsafe** string functions such as gets() and most uses of sprintf(). These are unsafe because you cannot reliably predict the buffer size you need.

The other class of string functions can be *used* safely provided you keep track of the maximum buffer sizes used and required correctly.

One way to help doing this in C++ is to use a nice class like StringPiece in Google's RE2 package, which is a pointer and length, where the pointer points into an NTBS. By storing the correct length into the StringPiece once, the class can then track the length of various operations. You can write such a class yourself. Doing this will not make your code correct but it will *isolate* the critical spots (namely, getting the arguments to the constructor right).

In this case, encapsulation is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

The standard C functions to convert between multibyte and wide characters are available: `mbtowc()`, `mbstowcs()`, `wctomb()`, `wcstombs()` and so on.