# Is there any windows specific SecureZeroMemory equivalent library function available in Linux (gcc 5.4)?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

We have written C++ code which compiles both on Windows and Ubuntu.
I want to use secure function `memset_s` for zeroing out buffers in my app.

Both Windows and Ubuntu 16.04 does not include definition of  `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__`  macro so I am not able to use `memset_s` provided by C++11.

On windows I have `SecureZeroMemory` which prevents compiler optimization.
On Ubuntu 16.04 (GCC version 5.4 ) I am looking for `SecureZeroMemory` equivalent library function (which will prevent compiler optimization).

It will be really helpful if you can suggest me library function in linux, end option is manual implemention memset_s for linux platform

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could use a loop + volatile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to guarantee code doing memory writes is not optimized away in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268657/is-it-possible-to-guarantee-code-doing-memory-writes-is-not-optimized-away-in-c)

Comment: XY problem? Why are you worried about compiler optimisations? And what does the buzzword *secure* have to do with it?

Comment: I believe Microsoft implements ISO/IEC TR 24731 (now part of the standard) so you have the safer string functions. glibc is not conforming so it is not part of the standard library. On Linux I think you install a dev library for it. I think it is libbsd, but I don't recall for sure. Also see [Safe String Functions In Mac OS X and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4570147/608639).

Comment: There's no `memset_s` in C++11, or in C++17 for that matter.

Comment: explicit_bzero is the equivalent of SecureZeroMemory

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure the memory is zeroed and that this operation is not optimized out by the compiler (because of the *as-if* rule), you can put an "optimizer barrier":

```
void always_memset(void* dest,int ch,size_t count){
     memset(dest,ch,count);
     //Make the compiler believe that you are using memory
     //including memory referenced by dest
     asm volatile("" : : :"memory");//it is possible to be more subtle.

     }
```

Then `memset_s` can easily be implemented by a call to this function after the precondition checks.

Comment: thanks for your response. But I wish to avoid use of memset itself Is there any SecureZeroMemory equivalent function in gcc or third party libraray ??

Comment: @TusharPatil I would be surprised if none of the crypto libraries available on linux did not provide a function to do that.